# standard input/ file input

Tags: arrays, file, input, pascal

I probably have a basic problem. I've been trying to read an array from file and AFTER that a string from standard input in Pascal language. It doesn't send an error message, it just doesn't wait 'till I write the input string on the screen. What should I do?

Here's my code:

```
Procedure beolvas(var x:rangsor; var n:byte; fajl:string);
var i:byte;

Begin
  Assign(input,fajl);
  Reset(input);
Readln(n);
for i:=1 to n do begin
   Readln(x[i].diak);
   Readln(x[i].atlag);
end;
close(input)
End;

Procedure beolvasnev(var s:string; x:rangsor; n:byte);
var i:byte;
Begin
Write('Kerem a diak nevet: ');
Readln(s);
End;
```

Comment: Never assume file access would succeed. Always check the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Assign(input, '');` (empty file name) after you've finished with the file variable, that's after you've called `close(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling the program from which file to read; in the absence of a file name, the program tries to read from the console, which explains you writing "it just doesn't wait till I write the input string on the screen" (shouldn't that be "it waits until I write the input string"?).

I don't know whether this is deliberate or not, but the first line of the file is expected to hold an integral value. It would be better to read from the file a string variable and then check whether the string is numerical before using it as a loop counter.